# If $K/F$ is a Galois extension and $[E:F]=2$, where $F\subset E\subset K$, is it true that $E/F$ is a Galois extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F \subset E \subset K$ be field extensions and $[E:F]=2$.
If $K/F$ is a Galois extension then $E/F$ is Galois.

This is true? Does anyone know how to prove it?

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Degree 2 extension is not always separable ($\Bbb{F_2}(t^{1/2})/ \Bbb{F_2}(t)$ is purely inseparable), but now $K/F$ is separable.

Subextension of a separable extension is separable, so $E/F$ is separable. Degree 2 extensions are normal, so $E/F$ is normal, thus Galois.